# R fill matrix or array with conditional lagged calculation in for loop

Tags: arrays, r, lag

I've dug through the list archive, and either I don't know the right words to ask this question or this hasn't come up before--

I have a simulation function where I track a list of points over time, and want to introduce an extra lagged calculation based on an assignment. I've created a very simple bit of code to understand how R fills in a matrix:

```
t<-21    #time step
N<-10    #points to track
#creating a matrix where it's easy for me to see how the calculation is done
NEE<-rep(NA, (t+1)*N);dim(NEE)<-c(N,(t+1))
for(i in 1:t){
    NEE[,1]<-1
    NEE[,i+1]<-NEE[,i]+5
}

#the thing to calculate
gt<-rep(0, (t+1)*N);dim(gt)<-c(N,(t+1))
#assigned states
veg<-c(rep(0,5), rep(1,5))
veg.com<-rep(veg, t);dim(veg.com)<-c(N,t)

for (i in 1:t){
    gt[,i+1]<-ifelse(veg.com[,i]==0, NEE[,i]/5, NEE[,i-3]/5)
}
#to have a view of what happens
veg1<-gt[1,]*5      #assignment for veg.com==0
veg2<-gt[10,]*5     #assignment for veg.com==1
what<-cbind(NEE[1,], veg1,veg2)
what
```

Of course it works, except how it fills in the first bit (shown here as the first 4 values in veg2 of what) before the lag is in effect when veg.com==1. I'm sure there're work arounds, but I first simply want to understand what R is doing in those initial few loops?

Answer (score 0):

The first two times through that second for-loop you will be using negative indexing with the expression

```
NEE[ , i-3]
```

That will return a 10 column matrix with removal of the 2nd column. The next iteration will return another 10 column matrix with removal of the first column. Negative indices remove portions of a matrix or dataframe in R